# Is ArgumentException right for a property in a model?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, argumentexception

When checking an parameter passed as a `string`, you would throw an `ArgumentException`.

```
void CheckName(string name)
{
    if (name != "Alice")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Name is not Alice.");
    }
}
```

However, when passing a model (object) to a function, and you check the model's properties and want to throw an exception. Which exception is the right one to throw? Is it still `ArgumentException`?

```
void CheckUser(UserModel model)
{
    if (model.Name != "Alice")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Name is not Alice."); // ?
    }
}
```

Should I include a `paramName` parameter in the exception?
Should the `paramName` be `Name` or `Model.Name`?

Comment: IMO I'd use `new ArgumentException("UserModel.Name is not Alice", "model");`

Answer (score 3):

> √ DO throw ArgumentException or one of its subtypes if bad arguments
>   are passed to a member. Prefer the most derived exception type, if
>   applicable.
>
> √ DO set the ParamName property when throwing one of the subclasses of
>   ArgumentException.
>
> This property represents the name of the parameter that caused the
>   exception to be thrown. Note that the property can be set using one of
>   the constructor overloads.

Taken from [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007(v=vs.110).aspx).

Yes, you can throw `ArgumentException` in this situation (with `model` parameter). But it seems that it is connected with your business logic so I would prefer creating a custom excpetion, e.g `InvalidUserException("This user is not allowed to do it.")` or something similar.

Comment: The Framework Design Guidelines does not seem to mention the appropriate action to be taken when it is a model, not a primitive parameter. It vaguely mentions "member".

Comment: That's why I proposed to create a custom exception. I believe ArgumentException are supposed to work with primitive parameters.